# How to get quotas of AWS via boto3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm working on boto3 - SDK python for AWS.

I am starting with simple service quota for ec2 but always ending up with the below error,

```
import boto3

quota_client = boto3.client('service-quotas')
response = quota_client.get_service_quota(
ServiceCode='ec2'
)
```

Error:

```
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'service- 
quotas'. Valid service names are: acm, acm-pca, alexaforbusiness, 
amplify, apigateway, apigatewaymanagementapi, apigatewayv2, 
application-autoscaling, appmesh, appstream, appsync, athena, 
autoscaling, autoscaling-plans, backup, batch, budgets, ce, chime, 
cloud9, clouddirectory, cloudformation, cloudfront, cloudhsm, 
cloudhsmv2, cloudsearch, cloudsearchdomain, cloudtrail, cloudwatch, 
codebuild, codecommit, codedeploy, codepipeline, codestar, cognito- 
identity, cognito-idp, cognito-sync, comprehend, comprehendmedical, 
config, connect, cur, datapipeline, datasync, dax, devicefarm, 
directconnect, discovery, dlm, dms, docdb, ds, dynamodb, 
dynamodbstreams, ec2, ecr, ecs, efs, eks, elasticache, 
elasticbeanstalk, elastictranscoder, elb, elbv2, emr, es, events, 
firehose, fms, fsx, gamelift, glacier, globalaccelerator, glue, 
greengrass, groundstation, guardduty, health, iam, importexport, 
inspector, iot, iot-data, iot-jobs-data, iot1click-devices, iot1click- 
projects, iotanalytics, iotevents, iotevents-data, iotthingsgraph, 
kafka, kinesis, kinesis-video-archived-media, kinesis-video-media, 
 kinesisanalytics, kinesisanalyticsv2, kinesisvideo, kms, lambda, lex- 
models, lex-runtime, license-manager, lightsail, logs, 
 machinelearning, macie, managedblockchain, marketplace-entitlement, 
 marketplacecommerceanalytics, mediaconnect, mediaconvert, medialive, 
 mediapackage, mediapackage-vod, mediastore, mediastore-data, 
mediatailor, meteringmarketplace, mgh, mobile, mq, mturk, neptune, 
 opsworks, opsworkscm, organizations, personalize, personalize-events, 
 personalize-runtime, pi, pinpoint, pinpoint-email, pinpoint-sms-voice, polly, pricing, 
 quicksight, ram, rds, rds-data, redshift, rekognition, resource-groups, 
 resourcegroupstaggingapi, robomaker, route53, route53domains, 
 route53resolver, s3, s3control, sagemaker, sagemaker-runtime, sdb, 
secretsmanager, securityhub, serverlessrepo, servicecatalog, 
servicediscovery, ses, shield, signer, sms, sms-voice, snowball, sns, sqs, 
ssm, stepfunctions, storagegateway, sts, support, swf, textract, 
transcribe, transfer, translate, waf, waf-regional, workdocs, worklink, 
workmail, workspaces, xray
```

The documentation page shows that service-quotas supported in boto3 but looks like it's not or am I doing anything incorrect here?

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/service-quotas.html

Comment: It works for me. Have you tried updating your `boto3` module?

Comment: yes i have updated the module and current version is 1.9.207. Is it the correct version ?

Comment: My version is 1.9.190. It's very likely the versions are clashing somewhere. You could try to downgrade as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem with my current `boto3-1.9.174 botocore-1.12.174` installation.

I then did:

```
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

It moved me to version `boto3-1.9.208 botocore-1.12.208` and it works fine.

I try to use Python virtual environments to isolate libraries for easy updating.

Comment: Thanks John, tried the same and its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

Actually, get_service_quota() api expects the following two arguments
ServiceCode
QuotaCode

For e.g. For EC2, ServiceCode is "ec2" and QuotaCode will be the parameter that you want to check for e.g. if you want to check "Attachments per VPC", you need to specify it's corresponding code "L-6DA43717". Those codes can be found at Service Quota page in the AWS console.